# Solr Spatial Time Search - Next Day Issue

Tags: mysql, date, datetime, time, solr

for a project I am looking for an advanced solution with Solr.
We have a database of > 1 Mio locations and their respective store hours. 
For each business we store up to 4 times per day, e.g.
Monday1, Monday2, Monday3, Monday4 (example 08:00, 12:00, 15:00, 18:00)
this would mean the store is open on Monday from 8-12 and 15-18

We setup Solr Spatial Search to be able to look for all stores which are open at lets say 16:00 on Monday which works pretty good. Issue is some stores are open for longer than the current day, e.g. 8pm - 2am. Logically this would be Monday 8pm - 0am and Tuesday 0am - 2am, but businesses would never write it that way so we save it as 8pm - 2am.

When I search for a business on Monday there is no issue, but as soon as I search for a business on Tuesday at 1am it does only consider businesses from Tuesday and the above mentioned store would not be found as "open", because the data is still saved for Mondays data.

Btw. I need two functions to work... on Monday 10pm I need to show how long this store is still open (so I need the value to be in Monday field) and on Tuesday I need to see whether this store is open at 1am though the data has been saved in Monday field –  elbd 7 mins ago

Any idea how this issue could be solved?
Would be much appreaciated (sorry, I am not a developer per se, so if you need more info let me know and I will get it from my dev, thanks!)